# Why do I get expression must be a modifiable lvalue?

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the following macro:

```
#define FOO(a,b) (--a)* 8 + (--b);
```

Now

```
int graph[8][8] = { 0 };
int *graph_p = &(graph[0][0]);
int *p = graph_p + FOO(2, 3);
```

Why do I get the error:

> IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue

Comment: Because `FOO(2, 3);` expands to `(--2)* 8 + (--3);` — you can't apply predecrement operators to constant integer values

Comment: What do you **think** should happen if you increment (i.e. **modify**) an integer **constant**?

Comment: Right... thank you all!

Comment: Don't write icky function-like macros and all your problems will go away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are passing an *integer constant* to function-like macro  `FOO(a, b)`, that applies pre-increment `--` operator to its arguments.

The result of this macro expansion looks as:

```
int *p = graph_p + (--2)* 8 + (--3);;
```

which is illegal in C, as operator requires a *modifiable lvalue* as its operand.

Another issues here are, that you should put parantheses around macro's replacement and do not place semicolon at the end:

```
#define FOO(a,b) ((--a)* 8 + (--b))
```

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
int *p = graph_p + FOO(2, 3);
```

will be replaced at compile time by the defined macro as

```
int *p = graph_p + (--2)* 8 + (--3);;
```

the operand of prefix `--` must be an lvalue. `2` and `3` are integer constants and it can't be an operand of prefix `--` operator.

Answer (score 1):

`FOO(2,3)` translates to `(--2)* 8 + (--3)`

You can only increment/decrement an lvalue, not a number.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Int * p=(int * )(graph-p+FOO(2,3));
```